# Only one instance of the Robot class should be created

Tags: matlab, webots

I am working on a Webots project using the Python R2021a version, in which four E-puck robots are used that push the box to target locations with the Python class for each robot "Class Environment, class robot followed by main control loop"

##### Error

While running, it is showing the following error message:

```
Only one instance of the Robot class should be created
Entering reset method...
Releasing existing supervisor instance...
WARNING: 'mycontroller1' controller exited with status: 1.
```

##### Code Snippet

```
_supervisor_instance = None

def __init__(self, use_supervisor=False):
  self.use_supervisor = use_supervisor
  self.TIME_STEP = 32
  self.receiver = None
  self.webots_supervisor = None
  if use_supervisor:
    if Environment._supervisor_instance is None:
      Environment._supervisor_instance = Supervisor()
    self.webots_supervisor = Environment._supervisor_instance
    self.robot = self.webots_supervisor.getFromDef("agent1")
  else:
    if Environment._robot_instance is None:
      Environment._robot_instance = Robot()
    self.robot = Environment._robot_instance

def reset(self):
  print(f"Supervisor: {self.webots_supervisor}")
  # Release existing Robot/Supervisor instance if it exists
  if self.use_supervisor:
    if Environment._supervisor_instance is not None:
      self.webots_supervisor = None
      self.robot = None
      del Environment._supervisor_instance
  else:
    if Environment._robot_instance is not None:
      self.robot = None
      del Environment._robot_instance
  # Create a new Robot/Supervisor instance
  if self.use_supervisor:
    Environment._supervisor_instance = Supervisor()
    self.webots_supervisor = Environment._supervisor_instance
    self.robot = self.webots_supervisor.getFromDef("agent1")
  else:
    if Environment._robot_instance is None:
      Environment._robot_instance = Robot()
    self.robot = Environment._robot_instance
  try:
    # Ensure that Supervisor instance is used when appropriate
    root = (
        self.webots_supervisor.getRoot()
        if self.use_supervisor
        else self. robot.getRoot()
    )
    self.print_node_names(root)
  except AttributeError as e:
    print(f"Error getting nodes: {e}")
```

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Can you please confirm if it is Python R2021a? R2021a seems MATLAB version though.

Comment: @ravi,its python.